# Убрать лишнее из строки

Tags: python-3.x

Есть строка:

a = b'26.00\r\n'

на выходе нужно получить только 26

как убрать лишние символы?

Comment: `int(float(a.decode("utf-8").strip()))` или `int(float(a.decode("utf-8").rstrip()))` здесь я заменил `strip()` на `rstrip()`, он будет удалять лишние символы (`\r`, `\n` или пробелы только справа (с конца) строки)

Comment: Пожалуйста, можете рассказать о Вашей задаче немного подробнее. Откуда у Вас эта строка? Что она содержит? В результате она также должна быть байтовой? В простейшем случае Вы просто можете взять первые 2 символа: `a[:2]`, но я думаю, это не то, что Вам нужно

Answer (score 1):

```
int(float(a.decode("utf-8").strip()))
```

или

```
int(float(a.decode("utf-8").rstrip()))
```

здесь я заменил `strip()` на `rstrip()`, он будет удалять лишние символы (`\r`, `\n` или пробелы только справа (с конца) строки)

---

- `a.decode("utf-8")` - превратит набор байт в строку
- `strip()` или `rstrip()` удалит `\r\n`
- `int(float(...))` преобразует строку сначала в вещественное число, затем в целое (нельзя напрямую преобразовать строку, содержащую число `float`, в `int`)

---

*OUPUT:*

> 26